# Рабочий скрипт google translate на curl

Tags: php, curl, google-translate

Подскажите рабочий скрипт перевода текстов google translate на curl (т.е. без всяких api и пр.) Перепробовал с десяток скриптов 2010-2014 годов - ни один не работает. Может есть у кого рабочий - поделитесь плиз.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, что именно не так, какая ошибка появляется и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Чем API не устраивает?
[Вот](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/), например, неплохая статейка на эту тему.

Comment: Работает ли сегодня код, приведённый в статье?

Comment: Копипастнуть код нельзя по двум причинам: во-первых, это не кошерно, во-вторых, статья чуть устарела, что, впрочем, не сильно искажает действительность - разве что иконки стали другие и на пару движений мышЫ больше сделать надо.  
Другими словами - не надо буквально следовать статье, это не инструкция, всё-таки...

Comment: "работает ли код" -- это *да/нет/не знаю* вопрос. Автор явно написал, что он пробовал *"с десяток скриптов 2010-2014 годов - ни один не работает"* Поэтому я не вижу смысла зачем добавлять ссылки на какой-то код, если он не был оттестирован сегодня.

Comment: @jfs, Хотелось бы отметить что автор не указал какие именно скрипты он пробовал, так что любой скрипт потенциально неиспользован был.
В статье есть главное - ссылки на API гугла, даже с примерами, которые, вроде, рабочие ([примеры](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/libraries) от гугла).
Я бы вообще проголосовал за закрытие, т.к. вопрос в принципе не объявлен, но снизошёл до указания API и примеров.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример:

```
<?php

//Переводим с Русского на Английский
//$apiKey – платный ключ от Гугл API
//$texttoen – текст для перевода

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($texttoen) . '&source=ru&target=en';

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handle);                 
$responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($handle);

//Выводим результат  
echo $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];

?>
```

Comment: Кстати, стоимость перевода вполне адекватная. Стоимость перевода составляет $20 за миллион знаков текста (или приблизительно $0,05 за страницу, из расчета 500 слов на страницу).

Answer (score 0):

Я не стану утверждать на 100%, но с большой вероятностью гугл в определенный момент заблокирует запросы с вашего сервера и запросит ввод капчи. Так что лучше используйте API.

Comment: Google Translate API это платный сервис. покупается определенное количество знаков. Но так-то да, это будет удобнее и надежнее.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что на данный момент API для работы с google translate уже платное, все решения ранее уже не работают.

Информация доступна на сайте [google](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/terms?hl=ru)